# Updating Node structure in SQL XML data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have some Data stored as XML in SQL Server that looks as follows:

```
<FormSearchFilter>
    .......
    <IDs>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>2</int>
    </IDs>
    .......
</FormSearchFilter>
```

This XML is mapped to a DTO and the data type for IDs is changing from a List to a string. As a result I now need to updae all existing XML: data to look as follows:

```
<FormSearchFilter>
    .......
    <IDs>1,2</IDs>
    .......
</FormSearchFilter>
```

Whats the best way to achieve this via an update query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the hint, that **this is a very bad idea!** you might try something like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
 Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 xml XML)

INSERT INTO @t(xml)
VALUES
 ('<FormSearchFilter><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int></IDs></FormSearchFilter>'),
 ('<FormSearchFilter><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int><int>3</int></IDs></FormSearchFilter>'),
 ('<FormSearchFilter><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int><int>3</int><int>4</int></IDs></FormSearchFilter>');

 UPDATE @t
 SET [xml]= (SELECT REPLACE([xml].query('data(/FormSearchFilter/IDs/int)').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),' ',',') AS IDs 
             FOR XML PATH('FormSearchFilter'));

 SELECT * FROM @t
```

### Explanation:

`XQuery` function `data()` will return alle `text()` nodes (in your case the int values) separated by a blank. This can be replaced with a comma to get the list needed.

### UPDATE: Preserve other elements (be aware, that the order changes)

```
INSERT INTO @t(xml)
VALUES
 ('<FormSearchFilter><test>x</test><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int></IDs></FormSearchFilter>'),
 ('<FormSearchFilter><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int><int>3</int></IDs><test>x</test></FormSearchFilter>'),
 ('<FormSearchFilter><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int><int>3</int><int>4</int></IDs></FormSearchFilter>');

 UPDATE @t
 SET [xml]= (SELECT  [xml].query('/FormSearchFilter/*[local-name()!="IDs"]') AS [*]
                    ,REPLACE([xml].query('data(/FormSearchFilter/IDs/int)').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),' ',',') AS IDs 
             FOR XML PATH('FormSearchFilter'));

 SELECT * FROM @t
```

Comment: This will not work if `FormSearchFilter` contains elements other than `IDs` which must be preserved, which the question seems to imply.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, well one could use this to create the new `<IDs>` element and then replace the existing node...

Comment: @JeroenMostert Depending on the rest, it might be enough to use `.query` in order to get all nodes below `<FormSearchFilter>` without the one with `local-name()="IDs"` and combine them in the `FOR XML PATH`

Comment: Not bad -- I don't think the reordering will be a problem in this scenario, since DTO mapping typically doesn't care about that). Attributes on `IDs` or blanks in `int` would also break this, but again, probably not an issue for this case. As usual, T-SQL's limitations make these things far more complicated than necessary ([`string-join`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xquery-operators-20021115/#func-string-join), anyone?)

Comment: @Shnugo That works. Agreed that its not a great idea and have in fact mitigated the need to do this by affecting a more root cause fix, but been helpful to see how XML data can be updated in this way.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, and if you're open to a helper Table-Valued Function.

**Example**

```
Declare @XML xml = '
<FormSearchFilter>
    <OtherContent>Some Content</OtherContent>
    <IDs>
        <int>1</int>
        <int>2</int>
    </IDs>
    <IDs>
        <int>11</int>
        <int>12</int>
        <int>13</int>
    </IDs>
    <IDs>
        <int>99</int>
    </IDs>
    <MoreContent>Some MORE Content</MoreContent>
</FormSearchFilter>
'


Select @XML = replace(cast(@XML as varchar(max)),RetVal,NewVal)
 From (
        Select *
              ,NewVal = stuff(replace(replace(RetVal,'<int>',','),'</int>',''),1,1,'')
         From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](cast(@XML as varchar(max)),'<IDs>','</IDs>')
      ) A

Select @XML
```

**Returns**

```
<FormSearchFilter>
  <OtherContent>Some Content</OtherContent>
  <IDs>1,2</IDs>
  <IDs>11,12,13</IDs>
  <IDs>99</IDs>
  <MoreContent>Some MORE Content</MoreContent>
</FormSearchFilter>
```

The TVF was created because I tired of extracting content (left,right,charindex,patindex,reverse,...).  It is a modifed parse/split function which accepts two non-like delimiters.  Just to illustrate, if you were to run:

```
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](cast(@XML as varchar(max)),'<IDs>','</IDs>')
```

The results would be

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1       65      <int>1</int><int>2</int>
2       100     <int>11</int><int>12</int><int>13</int>
3       150     <int>99</int>
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1 

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly elegant but does end up with the required output:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
 Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 xml XML)

INSERT INTO @t(xml)
VALUES
 ('<FormSearchFilter><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int></IDs></FormSearchFilter>'),
 ('<FormSearchFilter><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int><int>3</int></IDs></FormSearchFilter>'),
 ('<FormSearchFilter><IDs><int>1</int><int>2</int><int>3</int><int>4</int></IDs></FormSearchFilter>');

DECLARE @updates TABLE(
 Id INT,
 UpdatedValue XML
)

INSERT INTO @updates
SELECT 
 Id,
 (SELECT STUFF((
  SELECT 
   ',' + c.value('.', 'varchar')
  FROM @t t1
   CROSS APPLY t1.xml.nodes('//IDs/int') x(c)
  WHERE t1.Id = t.Id
  FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '') IDs
 FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM @t t

-- remove existing IDs node
UPDATE @t
 SET xml.modify('delete //IDs')

-- insert updated IDs node back in
UPDATE t
 SET xml.modify('insert sql:column("u.UpdatedValue") into (/FormSearchFilter)[1]')
FROM @t t
 JOIN @updates u ON t.Id = u.Id
```

Comment: [Don't use `VARCHAR` without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). In this case, it breaks your approach for any integer with more than one digit. Use `varchar(max)` as a simple fix.

Comment: It's worth noting that this does not preserve the order of other elements (since `IDs` is inserted at the end). This may or may not be a problem, depending on how the XML is processed.